# I am creating quiz app but fontSize is not working

Tags: react-native

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const Title = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text styles={styles.title}>Quizzier</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Title

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    title: {
        fontSize:80,
        fontWeight:"600",
    },
    container:{
        paddingVertical:16,
        justifyContent:"center",
    }
})
```

Explain:
I am creating quiz app watching video tutorial from youtube. Everything works just fine in video but it was IOS, mine is Android.

Problem: fontSize is not working.

Answer (score 2):

The prop is `style` not `styles`

```
const Title = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Quizzier</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```